# RubyGem 2.4.5.1 SSL Issue

Tags: rubygems

I am having an issue with rubygems 2.4.5.1.  When I run my code I get an error about SSL connection.  I found this link relating to the problem https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88.  This would be great except for the fact that it does not tell me how to fix the version I have.  I have also tried to revert back to an older version of rubygem but it does not seem to work.  Does anyone have suggestions on how to fix my problems (including reverting to an older version).  Thanks